# How to get the Millennium Falcon 75192

Tags: shopping

Just like everybody else, I'd like to get the new 75192 set. Unfortunately, information about that is rather spotty. The lego shop website used to write "soon", currently it writes "unavailable". The lego shop hotline says you *may* get it in a shop. When you call the shop, they don't have it. They *sometimes* get sets, but they are sold out in seconds. The online shop used to take reservations, even prepayment, but they stopped, the shops seemed to have done the same, but they stopped too.

So my question: What do I have to do, to get the 75192 *before* christmas?

Does somebody here have it? How did you get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutly want the Falcon before christmas
and if money is not a factor you can try 3rd party sellers like [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75192-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) or Ebay

It will cost you more than the offical price and  there will be shipping costs (it weighs 13150 gr.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware, that I can buy it for a lot of money. Unfortunately, money is a factor. I was hoping for hints, i.e. shops that still accept pre-orders or deposits, hints of the next deliveries and such things. And tales on how current owners got theirs...

Answer (score 3):

At my store, they said that it would be in stock in February. I think current inventory is going to a wait list of VIP members who were in the store on launch day. They also said that LEGO didn’t intend for it to be exclusive and that everyone should be able to get one. They were just surprised about interest!

Comment: Surprised by interest? That must have been a joke :) They probably surprised the owners of the 10179 Falcon that planned to sell it for a couple of thousand euros/dollars. I guess that now many people will rather get the new one for 800 Euro instead of paying much more for the 10179.

Answer (score 2):

It was in a status of "global shortage" as the demand is way ahead of supply - some official channels have a waiting list of hundreds to be filled as new stock trickles in. However, Lego has appeared to ramp up their supply, and it is available in major online channels as of May 2018 (https://www.zoolert.com/toys/lego/star-wars//millennium-falcon-75192/), this might have something to do with 4th of May.

This should last until 2019/2020 as the model stays under official production.