# The 75192 Millenium Falcon is available again!

Tags: shopping, star-wars

Or not? This evening, around 10 pm (in Germany), I noticed that the set was available. It is 11 pm now, and it returned to the "temporarily not available" status. Can it be sold out within one hour??

In the initial selling phase in 2017, the set had been available for some weeks. The buying limit was 3. I think it was limited to VIP members, but I think everyone who bought something directly from LEGO is a VIP member.

Anyway, according to [some rumors](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9457/how-to-get-the-millennium-falcon-75192?rq=1), the set would be available again in February. So I expected LEGO to produce as many Falcons as they can to flood the market after building up tension and demand. It seems, however, that 75192 will remain a rare set that will be sold out most of the time.

What I am really asking is this: Do you know or remember the situation regarding availabilty of similar sets in the past (e.g. the 10179 Falcon)? Does LEGO have a different selling strategy with the 75192?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can it be sold out within one hour?

Probably. If they sell all they have available, it would be "temporarily not available" again.

This set has been known to sell out the same day it becomes available in other countries.

Comment: I was surprised because in the initial selling phase in 2017 the set was available for several weeks. I expected that LEGO would flood the market with the sets after building up demand. Now it seems that the Falcon will still be a rare set.

Comment: Aziraphale, where are you from? Here in Belgium it sold out within minutes on initial launch online, also the physical lego stores had queues before opening time...

Comment: Here in Germany it took a while. In the end, I didn't buy one, but I had it in my virtual shopping cart.